# how to fill the listview background

Tags: android, background, android-listview

**Update 1**

Ok,

1. 1 is to do nothing.
2. 2 is listview.setBackground(Drawable)
3. 3 is the effect I am looking for.

[image]

---

listview only fill the background of an item , 
but I hope that item's background could fill the empty region of the listview.
what can i do?

[image: Hello]

thanks everyone,
Maybe my problem is not clear enough .
I know how to set the background of each Item , such as the red inside Item.
I also know how to use an image set ListView background , as the Empty text.
I hope the effect is used empty Item background to fill ListView's empty viewpart.
such as the right image, no item content ,just a background.

Comment: Sorry , you do not understand my question .
My question is, to fill the empty area of ​​the background by loop,
not one item background fill the all.

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing the white spaces unless you have padding or white on your individual row backgrounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , i try to post an image to explain on it but i can't ,

i create  custom layout with an item (60 px)  then i get the height of activity and by divided height of activity on 60 px  i get the number of items should put in the screen

then create custom adapter and in getView() method   i treatment   the logic of the text and background color.

and now i have an image like you updated .

regards

Comment: oh no...I have to do this?
any other solution?

Comment: i think it's will achieve your idea you need like the image says

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CCC"
 >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6cc"
    ></ListView>
```

Comment: thank for your help ,but, like @mango, this is not my question,
i know how to set the item background.

Comment: i think if you create custom layout for the listview  by divide the height of screen on the custom layout height you can get the number of  items to put in arrayAdapter, and i try this solution now

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent "
android:layout_height="match_parent "
android:background="@drawable/background"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but why not use setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable background) as you do and on your items set background to transparent? Of course your background will be stretched but that way you can insert another background image and you need not care about the item's background.